# problemas com @Injection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, cdi

Olá, pessoal. Estou criando um programa que manipula cadastros de pessoas e de gados. Neste programa, na tela de cadastro de gado, estou criando dois SelectOneMenu do primefaces. Um é de tipo de gado e o outro de raça do gado. Estes dois SelectOneMenus são dependentes. Ou seja, por exemplo, se o usuário selecionar "bovino" no tipo, na raça devem aparecer as raças bovinas para serem escolhidas.

Depois que comecei a implementar os SelectOneMenu (para ser mais preciso, quando implementei o de tipo de gado), começou a aparecer um erro de compilação **WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null**.

Pesquisei na internet e vários artigos falavam para alterar a versão do weld, mas eu tentei e o erro persiste. A versão atual que estou usando no projeto é a 2.3.5 Final. Já experimentei trocar esta versão no pom.xml e atualizar o projeto Maven, mas o erro persiste.

Este erro aparece quando tento carregar a página de cadastro de gado.
Uma coisa que acho estranho é que existem vezes que no console do Eclipse aparece o erro do WELD-001456 e tem vezes que aparece o erro **Cannot find component for expression "tipogado" referenced from "j_idt33:tipo".**.

Além disso, no console tem vezes que aparece em letra preta, uma mensagem avisando que não foi possível realizar o inject, mas esta mensagem também não aparece todas as vezes.

Estou enviando o código dos arquivos que acredito estarem relacionados.

**CadastroGado.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">#{cadastroGadoBean.editando ? "Edição de Gado" : "Novo Gado"}</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="gado" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado}"/>
        <f:event listener="#{cadastroGadoBean.inicializar}" type="preRenderView"/>
    </f:metadata>


    <h:form>
        <h1>#{cadastroGadoBean.editando ? "Edição de Gado" : "Novo Gado"}</h1>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/gado/CadastroGado" />
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar"
                    action="#{cadastroGadoBean.salvar}" update="@form" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
                <p:button value="Pesquisar" outcome="/gado/PesquisaGado"/>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
            style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipo"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="tipo" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.tipogado}" label="Tipo"
         required="true" requiredMessage="Informe o tipo do gado">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" noSelectionOption = "true"/>
            <f:selectItems 
                value="#{cadastroGadoBean.listTipo}" var="tipogado"
                itemValue="#{tipogado}"  itemLabel="#{tipogado.nomeTipo}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{cadastroGadoBean.carregarRacas}" update="tipogado"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Raça" for="gadoRaca" />
            <p:inputText id="gadoRaca" size="20" maxlength="80"
                value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoRaca}" required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe a raça do gado"
                             validatorMessage="formato de raça inválida">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <p:outputLabel value="Peso(em Kg)" for="gadoPeso" />
            <p:inputMask id="gadoPeso" size="10" maxlength="80"
                value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoPeso}" required="true" mask="999"
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe o peso do gado">

                <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" maximum="30"/>
            </p:inputMask>

            <p:outputLabel value="Sexo" for="sexo" />
            <p:selectOneRadio id="sexo" value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.sexo}"  required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe o sexo do gado">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Macho" itemValue="Macho"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fêmea" itemValue="Fêmea"/>
            </p:selectOneRadio>


            <p:outputLabel value="Nascimento" for="gadoNasc" />
            <p:calendar id="gadoNasc" size="10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoNasc}" maxdate="#{cadastroGadoBean.dataAtual}"
                locale="pt_BR" required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe a data de nascimento"/>


            <p:outputLabel value="Finalidade do Gado" for="gadoFinalidade" />
            <p:inputText id="gadoFinalidade" size="20" maxlength="80"
                value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.gadoFinalidade}" required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe a finalidade do gado"
                             validatorMessage="formato de nome inválido">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$"/>
            </p:inputText>

            <p:outputLabel value="Tag" for="tag"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.tag}" label="Tag" id="tag" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"  required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe a tag acoplada ao gado">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" noSelectionOption = "true"/>
                <f:selectItems 
                    value="#{cadastroGadoBean.listTags}" 
                    var="tag"
                    itemValue="#{tag}" 
                    itemLabel="#{tag.descricao}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:outputLabel value="Usuario" for="usuario"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastroGadoBean.gado.usuario}" label="Usuario" id="usuario" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                             required="true" 
                            requiredMessage="Por favor, informe o usuario que está efetuando o cadastro">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" noSelectionOption = "true"/>
                <f:selectItems 
                    value="#{cadastroGadoBean.listUsuario}" 
                    var="usuario"
                    itemValue="#{usuario}" 
                    itemLabel="#{usuario.nome}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**CadastroGadoBean.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.Gado;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Raca;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Tag;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.TipoGado;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.Usuario;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.RacaRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.TagsRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.TipoGadoRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.repository.UsuariosRep;
import com.sisRastrbov.services.CadastroGadoService;
import com.sisRastrbov.util.jsf.FacesUtil;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroGadoBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private TipoGadoRep tipoGados;

@Inject
private TagsRep tagsRep;

@Inject
private UsuariosRep usuarios;

@Inject
private CadastroGadoService cadastroGadoService;

private Gado gado;

private Tag tag;

private Usuario usuario;

private TipoGado tipogado;

private List<SelectItem> listTipo;

private List<SelectItem> listRaca;

private List<SelectItem> listTags;

private List<SelectItem> listUsuario;

public Date getDataAtual() {
    return new Date();
}

public CadastroGadoBean() {
    limpar();

}

public boolean isEditando() {
    boolean resultado = false;
    if (this.gado != null) {
        resultado = gado.getGadoId() != null;
    }
    return resultado;
}

public void inicializar() {

    listTipo = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    listTags = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    listUsuario = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    List<TipoGado> tipos = tipoGados.raizes();
    List<Tag> tags = tagsRep.raizes();
    List<Usuario> listaUsu = usuarios.listaDeUsu();

    for (TipoGado tg : tipos) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(tg.getNomeTipo());
        item.setValue(tg);
        listTags.add(item);
        System.out.println(listTipo);
    }

    for (Tag t : tags) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(t.getDescricao());
        item.setValue(t);
        listTags.add(item);
        System.out.println(listTags);
    }

    for (Usuario u : listaUsu) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(u.getNome());
        item.setValue(u);
        listUsuario.add(item);

    }

    if(!isEditando()){
        gado.setgadoStatus("Ativo");
    }

    if (this.tipogado != null) {
        tipos = tipoGados.raizes();
    }

}

public void limpar() {
    gado = new Gado();
    listTags = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

}

public void salvar() {

    this.gado = cadastroGadoService.salvar(this.gado);
    limpar();
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Gado salvo com sucesso!");

}

public void carregarRacas(){
    listRaca = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<Raca> racas = RacaRep.racasDe(gado.getTipogado());
    for (Raca r : racas) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(r.getNome());
        item.setValue(r);
        listRaca.add(item);
    }
}

public Gado getGado() {
    return gado;
}

public void setGado(Gado gado) {
    this.gado = gado;

    if (this.gado != null) {
        this.tag = this.gado.getTag();
    }
}

public List<SelectItem> getListTags() {
    return listTags;
}

public void setListTags(List<SelectItem> listTags) {
    this.listTags = listTags;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListTipo() {
    return listTipo;
}

public void setListTipo(List<SelectItem> listTipo) {
    this.listTipo = listTipo;
}

public Tag getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(Tag tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListUsuario() {
    return listUsuario;
}

public void setListUsuario(List<SelectItem> listUsuario) {
    this.listUsuario = listUsuario;
}

public TipoGado getTipogado() {
    return tipogado;
}

public void setTipogado(TipoGado tipogado) {
    this.tipogado = tipogado;
}
}
```

**TipoGado.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tipoGado")
public class TipoGado {

String nomeTipo;

@Id
@Column(name = "nomeTipo")
public String getNomeTipo() {
    return nomeTipo;
}

public void setNomeTipo(String nomeTipo) {
    this.nomeTipo = nomeTipo;
}
}
```

**Raca.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "raca")
public class Raca {


private String nome;
private TipoGado tipogado;


@Id
@Column(name = "racaNome")
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "nomeTipo")
public TipoGado getTipogado() {
    return tipogado;
}

public void setTipogado(TipoGado tipogado) {
    this.tipogado = tipogado;
}
}
```

**TipoGadoRep.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.TipoGado;

public class TipoGadoRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject 
private EntityManager manager;

public List<TipoGado> raizes(){
    return  manager.createQuery("from TipoGado",TipoGado.class).getResultList(); 
}

public List<TipoGado> listarTipoGado() {
    List<TipoGado> tipos = new ArrayList<TipoGado>();
    tipos = manager.createQuery("from TipoGado", TipoGado.class).getResultList();
    return tipos;
}

}
```

**RacaRep.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.sisRastrbov.model.Raca;
import com.sisRastrbov.model.TipoGado;

public class RacaRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private static EntityManager manager;

public static List<Raca> racasDe(TipoGado tipogado){
    return manager.createQuery("from Raca where nomeTipo = :raiz", Raca.class)
            .setParameter("raiz", tipogado).getResultList();
}

}
```

Comment: Você esta dando update em tipogado mas este componente não existe, veja:

```<p:ajax listener="#{cadastroGadoBean.carregarRacas}" update="tipogado"/>```

atualize o componente correto.